# Как задать специальний атрибут для чисел из некоторого диапазона?

Tags: python

Скажем так, у меня есть задача присвоить значениям - атрибут-число

```
1-10 attribute 1
11-20 attribute 2
21-30 attribute 3
....
(n-9)-n attribute n
```

Идея какая, я получаю число скажем так 14 и я точно могу сказать что это будет атрибут-число 2

```
value = 14 

??? do something 

result = 2
```

Думал может использовать `%` оператор но ничего толкового не приходит в голову

Answer (score 2, accepted):

можно так:

```
from math import ceil

def my_attr(a: int):
    return ceil(a/10)

print(my_attr(10))
print(my_attr(11))
print(my_attr(21))
```

```
1
2
3
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!